# How can I "force" adding a keyframe?

Tags: animation, workflow, keyframes

If I have *Only Insert Needed* turned on in my prefs, is there a way to "force-add" a keyframe when the value isn't changing, without having to:

- go into prefs,
- turn off *Only Insert Needed*,
- add the keyframe,
- go back into prefs and turn it back on?

[image: Prefs dialog showing 'Only Insert Needed' checkbox]

Or is this something I'm going to have to script?

Comment: Why do you need to keep it on? Otherwise, you can still press I to call the *Insert Keyframe Menu*.

Comment: It keeps the timeline tidier, and works better for the way I animate. If it's on and I press `i` at a point where the value is not changing I get the menu, but it doesn't insert anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I want to keep *Only Insert Needed* on for the way I work, but still needed to be able to drop keyframes into static channels, I created a custom script that force-adds keyframes for position x,y,z and Euler x,y,z rotation, and assigned a hotkey to it. In the case in point I only needed these keyframes, the script could be easily adapted to add other keys.

https://github.com/stibinator/stibs_blender_scripts/blob/main/force%20KF.py

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to key only the changed values, I'd simply disable *Only Insert Needed*.

Now if you need that most of the time, you can enable that option in the autokey's popover to force key all the keying set:

[image: Option]

You can add it to the quick favorites or assign to a custom keyboard shortcut via <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>.

[image: RMB menu]

And finally, as long as you don't have any keying set selected in your keying popover, you can always call the *Insert Keyframe Menu* at any time by pressing <kbd>I</kbd>.

[image: Insert keyframe menu]